# Where is _on function defined in jquery-file-upload Javascript library?

Tags: jquery-file-upload

After setting up  , I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on the line of 1273 which is the following

```
this._on(this.options.dropZone, {
```

I can't find where the function is defined in the javascript file (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js). Do I have to use it with other Javascript files in the package?

Answer (score 3):

it looks You haven't connected widget part of jquery.
  http://jqueryui.com/download/#!themeParams=none
I had the same problem, so I added it and now file upload works.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I get this problem sorted out with a whole jquery-ui library. I will test on a correct version of widget.js to see whether the file alone will work or not later.